# PHP - Get reference of item added into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable named `$results` where my code successfully loads some data from a database. I want to iterate over these results and create an object that follows this format:

```
[
    {
        "category": "categoryName",
        "elements": [
            { 
                 "id": 1,
                 "name": "elementName"
            }
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

In order to do that, I have the following code:

```
$response_data = [];

foreach ($results as $result) {
        
    $category = null;
    foreach ($response_data as &$data) {
        if ($data["category"] === $result->slug) {
            $category = &$data;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (is_null($category)) {
        $category = [ "category" => $result->slug, "elements" => [] ];
        $response_data[] = $category;
    }

    $category["elements"][] = [
        "id" => $result->post_id,
        "src" => $result->meta_value
    ];

    unset($category);
}

return $response_data;
```

As you can see, I'm getting the reference of every element in the `response_data` array in order to add a element to a category if it already exists, **or I create the category if it doesn't exist and add the element after**. The issue it's in this last part, the element is not added when it enters the if statement `if (is_null($category)`. I'm guessing that the reference of `$category` isn't the same as the reference of the same element when added to the array... Is that it? Can I get the reference of the object added to the array without iterating all of it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, you never "get a reference", you bind two (or more) variables together by reference. Neither variable is a "reference to" the other, they're both references to the same unnamed value.

It's arguably clearer to write `$category =& $data;` reacher than `$category = &$data;` to represent "assign by reference" rather than "get a reference and assign it".

Any assignment that's not by reference is by value - it might get optimised under the hood, but *conceptually* it takes a copy of the value, and sets the variable to that copy. (Objects are a bit special, because their "value" is itself a sort of pointer to somewhere else; that's different from "assign by reference", and not relevant here.)

The crucial line in your code is this:

```
$response_data[] = $category;
```

That takes *the current value of `$category` at that point in the program* and assigns it to a new element in the `$response_data` array. It doesn't make any relationship between those two variables, so when you later write to `$category["elements"]`, it doesn't affect the copy that was already made.

To bind them together, you need another assign by reference: `$response_data[] =& $category;` or equivalently `$category =& $response_data[];` (remember that PHP references don't remember their direction).

Alternatively, you could avoid the confusion of references by tracking the *key* of the matching category in the final array, and overwriting that key with modified data:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
        
    $category = null;
    $categoryKey = null;
    foreach ($response_data as $key => $data) {
        if ($data["category"] === $result->slug) {
            $category = $data;
            $categoryKey = $key;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (is_null($category)) {
        $category = [ "category" => $result->slug, "elements" => [] ];
    }

    $category["elements"][] = [
        "id" => $result->post_id,
        "src" => $result->meta_value
    ];

    if (is_null($categoryKey)) {
        $response_data[] = $category;
    }
    else {
        $response_data[$categoryKey] = $category;
    }
}

return $response_data;
```

Comment: However, the code you provided only adds an element to a category if the category doesn't exist yet (`$new` is true) but it doesn't add elements to an existing category. That's the part I believe "referencing" or "binding" is needed

Comment: @JaviAlbors You're quite right, my code didn't actually work as intended, sorry! I've updated it with a different version which I *think* will work properly, although I haven't actually tested (because you didn't give a [mre]). Just to show how it can be done without references.

Comment: [ImSop doesn't personally agree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914758/2943403), but for PSR-12 compliance the rhe ampersand must be attached to the variable, not the assignment operator.  It is not a combined operator.

Comment: @mickmackusa  PSR-12 says no such thing. Its only two mentions of "reference" are for reference parameters in signatures. My assertion is that analysing assignment by reference as a binary `=` operator and a separate unary `&` operator cannot explain its behaviour, which changes the state of both variables symmetrically. Nor can you use `&` as a general-purpose unary operator outside of such an assignment. Therefore either it is a binary operator, and PSR-12 mandates the spacing I suggest here, or it is not an operator at all but a special case syntax, and PSR-12 makes no ruling on it.

Comment: Time update the PHP docs then. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php  How sad that a PHP operator should be used with one style one way, and another style in another. I prefer consistency.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, if I get round to it, I'll post a PR standardising on the `$foo =& $bar` style and see what others think; I know I'm not alone in preferring it. It would also make sense of it being listed under "assignment operators". As far as consistency goes, I tend to think of `&` as more of a "modifier" than an operator (it doesn't have a *result*, it has an *effect*), and in this case it modifies the assignment, not the variable; for return by reference, it modifies the whole function; for reference parameters, there's not really any way to indicate it modifying the passing behaviour.